# Execute a sequentially function that executes fetch

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I need to execute `handleCursor` sequentially. How can I do that?

`handleCursor` is making a fetch request and looks like it returns before the fetch api request and WriteData is complete. The only way to "fix it" I could found was to put everything in a single big function but that looks very ugly.

```
 function Fill(cursor, diff ){
  for (var i = 0; i < diff; i++) {
        // get the latest html htmlNode written by WriteData
        let htmlNode = document.querySelect("lastCursorElem");
        const cursor = cursorHistory.top.pop(); 
       try{
          handleCursor(cursor, htmlNode);
       }
       catch(err) { 
        console.log(err);
        return;
      } 
   }
   return;
};

function handleCursor(cursor, htmlNode){ 
   fetch(cursor).then(
    function(response) {
      switch (response.status) {
        case 200:
          response.text().then(function(data) { 
            var next = response.headers.get("next");
            WriteData(next, data, htmlNode) ;
            return;
          }).
            catch(function(err) {
              console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
            });
          break;
        default:
          return;
      }
    }
  ).
    catch(function(err) {
      console.log('Fetch Error :', err);
    });
}
```

Comment: `return` the promise that you have and use `async`/`await` in the loop

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this (untested):

```
async function Fill (cursor, diff) {
  for (var i = 0; i < diff; i++) {
    // get the latest html htmlNode written by WriteData
    const htmlNode = document.querySelector('lastCursorElem')
    const cursor = cursorHistory.top.pop() 

    try {
      const response = await fetch(cursor)
      const data = await response.text()

      if (res.ok) {
        WriteData(response.headers.get('next'), data, htmlNode)
      } else {
        console.log('response was not 200-299')
      }
    } catch (err) { 
      console.log(err)
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not make handleCursor async and use await on it? const `res` should be `const response`, right?

Comment: OP didn't want "*to put everything in a single big function*", so it would've nice if you had preserved `handleCursor` as a separate function

Comment: Sure, you can handle it in two functions if you want. I mostly did what i would have done, feels less like a need to have two functions when you can use async/await

Comment: I would also have lowercased all my function names, It should only start with a uppercase if it's a class